# Copy folders recursively Without the folder content in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to copy a folder structure without copying the files.

I knew i can copy with `fs-extra copy`
This function can copy recursively, but i didn't find a way to not copy the files.

Comment: Synchronous code or Asynchronous code?

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

/**
 * Look ma, it's cp -R.
 * @param {string} src  The path to the thing to copy.
 * @param {string} dest The path to the new copy.
 */
var copyRecursiveSync = function(src, dest) {
  var exists = fs.existsSync(src);
  var stats = exists && fs.statSync(src);
  var isDirectory = exists && stats.isDirectory();
  if (isDirectory) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dest);
    fs.readdirSync(src).forEach(function(childItemName) {
      copyRecursiveSync(path.join(src, childItemName),
                        path.join(dest, childItemName));
    });
  }
};
```